# Add categorical feature before the dense layer in Keras?

Tags: python, merge, keras

I am working on a CNN model and want to add a new categorical feature before the Dense layer. I tried to concatenate the feature to the flattened output of CNN layer but looks like the concatenate function in Keras requires input of tensors and not arrays. How should I go about it? Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (6, 6), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (6, 6)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
```

I am trying to use Concatenate function but it can join tensors, where as my feature is a numpy array of shape (1, 3). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new model on side of your actual model.
This second model will take in input your numpy array and does nothing else.

Then you concatenate them.

Like this ->

```
m1 = Sequential()
m1.add(Conv2D(128, (6, 6), padding='same'))
m1.add(Activation('relu'))
m1.add(Conv2D(128, (6, 6)))
m1.add(Activation('relu'))
m1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
m1.add(Dropout(0.25))
m1.add(Flatten())

m2 = Sequential()
m2.add(Input()) # Put needed infos to input your numpy array
#Don't forget to flatten it if needed ?

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([m1,m2], mode='concat'))
#Then add your final layer.
#To train it, in place of the normal var X_train, you'll use [X_train,yournumpyarray] in model.train method
```

Comment: Thank you @Pusheen. I was actually confused in the concatenation process(which only concatenates the tensors) and didn't realize that the Input function changes the array to a tensor.

Comment: No problem, I had a similar issue some times ago.
Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it's ok for you :)